# Having issues with Php zip download code

Tags: php

i am trying to add images to zip file and forcing it with headers to download it. Below are the code snippet which i am using right now.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip_name = 'design_images_'.time() .".zip";
if($zip->open($zip_name, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE)!==TRUE){
    $error .= "* Sorry ZIP creation failed at this time";
}
    $i = 0;
foreach($valid_files as $file){
    $image_name = 'design_image_' . $i;
    $zip->addFile($file, $image_name);
    $i++;
}
$zip->close();
if(file_exists($zip_name)){
    // force to download the zip
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
    readfile($zip_name);

}
```

When i try to open the zip file it gives error: the archive is corrupt.

Comment: Are you sure there's no error at `zip->open`? Is there any output after `readfile`?

Comment: Yes, zip is downloaded successfully with accurate size but not able to extract it. When i double click the zip file i can see all the images inside it with proper size too. But same not able to open or extract any one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the output buffer before serving the download:

```
if(file_exists($zip_name)){

  // Clean the output buffer.
  while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
  }

  // force to download the zip
  header("Pragma: public");
  header("Expires: 0");
  header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
  header("Cache-Control: private",false);
  header('Content-type: application/zip');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$zip_name.'"');
  readfile($zip_name);

}
```